# python boto3, upload file to s3 return False but no exception

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

```
try:
        
        if s3.meta.client.upload_file(fileLocation, bucket_name, objectName) is True:
            print("Upload log file to s3 bucket")
        else:
            print('Upload file to s3 bucket failed')
            return False
    except s3.exceptions:
        print("known error occured")
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

I run this code but then it prints `Upload file to s3 bucket failed` , no exception happens so I have no idea why it failed. The s3 bucket exists since I got the bucket_name from list all existing buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3.meta.client.upload_file` doesn't return anything as per documentation, so you have `None` and it falls into else, have you checked that file in S3?

Also،  check if you have lesding slash (/) in your path, your file may end in a newly crested folder 'uploads' in the bucket.

Comment: Yeah, just found the reason, that function doesn't return anything, after waiting for sometime, the upload file show up in the s3